# Kubernetes force delete RC not deleting

Tags: kubernetes

I'm not able to delete one of the replication controller no matter what, seems like it is corrupted as it is affecting some components.

```
 kubectl delete rc kube-dns-v20  --namespace=kube-system
error: timed out waiting for "kube-dns-v20" to be synced
```

Tried with several options like cascade=false, it says deleted, when actually it is not deleting it.

```
kubectl delete rc kube-dns-v20  --namespace=kube-system --force=true --cascade=false
replicationcontroller "kube-dns-v20" deleted
```

Any other way in which this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Attempt setting the grace-period to 0?

`kubectl delete rc kube-dns-v20 --force=true --grace-period=0 --namespace=kube-system`

Comment: Nope, didnt work,...`kubectl delete rc kube-dns-v20 --force=true --grace-period=0 --namespace=kube-system
warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.`
error: timed out waiting for "kube-dns-v20" to be synced

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Have you tried deleting the associated "deploymentconfig"? You can find it with `kubectl get dc` and then delete with `kubectl delete dc <name>`.